# Showing a Vector is orthogonal to a Line

Tags: vector-spaces, orthogonality

In order to show two vectors are orthogonal to each other, their dot product must be 0. How does this extend to lines? The question I have is as follows:

Show that the vector **w** is orthogonal to the line **w**$^T$**x**+$b=0$. Hint: Consider two points, **x$_1$** and **x$_2$** that lie on the line. What is the inner product of **w**$^T$(**x$_1$** - **x$_2$**)?

Here is what I have so far. In order to for the vector **w** to be orthogonal to the line **w**$^T$**x**+$b=0$, the dot product between them must be $0$. Observe,

$$[w_1, w_2]^T[x_1, x_2] + b =0$$
$$w_1x_1 + w_2x_2 + b = 0$$

I feel like the answer is supposed to obvious, but I also do not know how the hint becomes useful.

Comment: I think it is like $w^tx_1+b=0=w^tx_2+b$ so $w^t(x_2-x_1)=0.$

Answer (score 1):

To prove that **w** is orthogonal to the line **w**$^T$**x** + $b$ = $0$, take 2 points on the line. Let these points be **x**$_1$ and **x**$_2$, since these 2 points lie on the line they will satisfy:

**w**$^T$**x**$_1$$+ \ b = 0$

**w**$^T$**x**$_2$$+ \ b = 0$

Subtracting these 2 equations will give you,

**w**$^T$(**x**$_1$-**x**$_2$)$= 0$

Giving you the result. I hope this helps.